# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: azure, botframework

I am trying to access an azure resource(QNA) using keys which I have copied from the azure portal:

```
           // <Authorization>
              var subscriptionKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx");
        var client = new QnAMakerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey)) { Endpoint = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/" };
        // </Authorization>

        // <EndpointKey>
        var endpointhostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("iakpmgpoc.azurewebsites.net");
        var endpointKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx");
```

still getting "unauthorized access" issue

Comment: Can you try adding `var runtimeClient = new QnAMakerRuntimeClient(new EndpointKeyServiceClientCredentials(endpointKey)) { RuntimeEndpoint = $"https://{endpointhostName}.azurewebsites.net" };` after the endpointKey line and test and see if it works?

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using the correct endpoint and subscription keys as well as the region